# How to use Locators on a graphic in a tabview

Tags: manipulate

Background:
 I want to split graphics in a Manipulate in several parts in a tabview control. But the tabview somehow interferes with the locators as in the following simplified example:

```
 Manipulate[
  TabView[{aa -> Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 1], 
    bb -> 1}] , {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

Question: How to use Locators on a graphic in a tabview. ( How to get the snippet above working ? )

EDIT:

I left out too much in the previous example, this is a better description.

```
  Manipulate[
   pts1 = pts;
  TabView[{
    a -> Graphics[Line[pts1]],
    b -> Graphics[Line[pts]]}],
  {{pts, ptsI}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, 
  Initialization -> {pts = {{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.6}}}]
```

So, there is one set of data, in this example pts. In one part of the display (A) the data is modified, the data is then shown on ( B ). -

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
pltrng = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};

Manipulate[pnts = LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], 
   Dynamic @ Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> pltrng], 
   LocatorAutoCreate -> True];
 tbl = Dynamic @ Grid[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, p]];
 ln = Dynamic @  Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng]; 
 bzc = Dynamic @ Graphics[{Blue, BezierCurve[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 dsk = Dynamic @ Graphics[{Orange, Disk[#, .1] & /@ p}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 plygn = Dynamic@ Graphics[{Green, Polygon[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 allviews =  Grid[{{pnts, tbl, dsk}, {ln, bzc, plygn}}, Dividers -> {All, All}];
 Dynamic @ TabView[{"locators" -> pnts, "table" -> tbl, "line" -> ln, 
   "beziercurve" -> bzc, "disks" -> dsk, "polygon" -> plygn, "all" -> allviews}, 
   Alignment -> Center], 
 {{p, {{-.5, -0.5}, {-.25, .5}, {.6, 0.6}}}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I think this is exactly what he had in mind. However, the `LocatorAutoCreate` doesn't work as expected for me... Instead of creating a new one, it simply moves the previously selected one.

Comment: @R.M Works OK for me. Remember to press "Alt - Mouse Click" instead of just "Mouse Click" to create a Locator

Comment: @R.M and belisarius thank you for the votes. I had to change the setting for `LocatorAutoCreate` to `True` from `All` in OP's question. With this setting, as belisarius notes, one needs to use `Alt-Click` to create a new locator.

Comment: @belisarius Ah, thanks. Cmd-click for me. Indeed, it was because of what kguler says in his comment... I tried the OP's code which had `All` and created locators with a simple click and tried that here too :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ndroock1, glad it worked for you.

Comment: `LocatorAutoCreate ` requires an additional button to be pressed. On MacOS this is the Mac-Button next to the Spacebar. Look up the documentation for `LocatorAutoCreate ` on your OS.

Comment: @kglr In your last edit, you removed the assignment `pts1 = p` but didn't update all the instances where `pts1` occur.

Comment: thanks @MichaelE2 for catching the edit glitch.  Will fix in a moment.

Answer (score 9):

One way to get it working is to do something like

```
Manipulate[TabView[{
   aa -> LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], Dynamic@Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 1]], 
   bb -> 1}], 
 {{p, {1, 1}}, None}]
```

Comment: This one has the additional benefit of allowing the usage of **Dynamic[p]** on the second tab

Comment: This works Heike, it may or may not be a solution to my problem but it definitely gives me something to study and work on. I just need a LOT of screen real estate to display graphics and manipulate it with controls. The best way to handle this is with tabs in my opinion and a lot of programs work like that.

Comment: I have edited ( improved ) the question. Your solution did not work ( immediately ) but I am still working with your idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can move the `TabView` outside the `Manipulate` and it works:

```
TabView[{
    aa -> Manipulate[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}], 
    bb -> 1}
]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Damn ... by 10 seconds :)

Comment: @belisarius :-D

Comment: I have Manipulates per tabview at the moment and that causes a lot of sync problems.

Comment: @ndroock1 I don't quite understand what you mean by "manipulates per tabview"

Comment: @R.M - Like TabView[a->Manipulate[],b->Manipulate[],...] that works somewhat with an outer Manipulate but it is infact a workaround for the problem proposed in this question.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me if I change parameter list name coherently:

```
pltrng = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};

Manipulate[
 pnts = LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], 
   Dynamic@Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> pltrng], 
   LocatorAutoCreate -> True];
 tbl = Dynamic@Grid[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, p]];
 ln = Dynamic@Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 bzc = Dynamic@Graphics[{Blue, BezierCurve[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 dsk = Dynamic@
   Graphics[{Orange, Disk[#, .1] & /@ p}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 plygn = Dynamic@Graphics[{Green, Polygon[p]}, PlotRange -> pltrng];
 allviews = 
  Grid[{{pnts, tbl, dsk}, {ln, bzc, plygn}}, Dividers -> {All, All}];
 Dynamic@TabView[{"locators" -> pnts, "table" -> tbl, "line" -> ln, 
    "beziercurve" -> bzc, "disks" -> dsk, "polygon" -> plygn, 
    "all" -> allviews}, 
   Alignment -> Center], {{p, {{-.5, -0.5}, {-.25, .5}, {.6, 0.6}}}, 
  None}]
```

[image]

This shows that `LocatorAutoCreate` works brilliantly. Press Mac-button on MacOS and the Windows-button in addition and simultaneous with the positioning click, right-click.