# How can I prevent TabView from resetting the current tab?

Tags: functions, manipulate, built-in-symbols, locator, user-interface

This is a simplification of a problem that has arisen in a project regarding Euclidean activities for verifying proportions via operations
on pairs of magnitudes.  In the project, the LocatorPane is used to enter values for x, y that will be used in carrying out operations on pairs of line segments in order to allow the user to ascertain whether the line segments reflect the ratio, y:x, where x, y are positive integers.

The code below captures the essence of the technical problem I have run into.

I am using LocatorPane to select values (x,y) that will be used in each of the tabs in TabView.  However, each time a new locator value is selected, the TabView defaults to the first tab, 1.  To test this, click on either tab 2 or tab 3; then set the locator value.  TabView will automatically reset to tab 1.

**Test Code**

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   TabView[{
     1 -> Row[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]]}, "\t"],
     2 -> Row[{2*pt[[1]], 2*pt[[2]]}, "\t"],
     3 -> Row[{3*pt[[1]], 3*pt[[2]],}, "\t"]}],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]}]]
```

[image]

---

I tried a variation in which a LocatorPane is placed within each tab, but the reset problem continues to occur.

Comment: related? [How to use Locators on a graphic in a tabview](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5506/125)

Comment: @kglr. Nice example, from which I can learn.  I'm wondering why you didn't have to use Dynamic before TabView, as Michael E2 suggested.

Comment: DavidC, added `Dynamic` after an eight year delay:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some `Dynamic[]` and a variable to keep track of the selected tab:

```
Manipulate[Row[{
   Dynamic@TabView[{
      1 -> Pane[Row[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]]}, "\t"], 150],
      2 -> Pane[Row[{2*pt[[1]], 2*pt[[2]]}, "\t"], 150],
      3 -> Pane[Row[{3*pt[[1]], 3*pt[[2]]}, "\t"], 150]
      }, Dynamic@i], 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]}], {{pt, {0., 
    0.}}, None}, {{i, 1}, None}]
```

Oh, I added a `Pane` because it was a pain with the graphics jumping around depending on how many digits were displayed.

The `Dynamic@TabView[...]` keeps the whole body of the `Manipulate` from being re-executed when `pt` is changed (which interrupts dragging the `Locator`).

Comment: Very nice.  However, I am puzzled as to how Mathematica knows that `i` stands for the current tab.

Comment: @DavidC From the second argument `Dynamic@i`.  See the first bullet point under "Details" in the docs for `TabView`; there are examples under "Scope" as well.

Comment: @DavidC I was a little lazy with my explanation: The re-execution (if no `Dynamic`) does not reset `i` to `1`, so the tab view is preserved; rather, it interrupts dragging the `Locator`, so it is still necessary.  I was misremembering one my trial runs.